# Como fazer o método findById no spring-boot?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot, gradle

Estou fazendo uma Api onde preciso pegar as informações de um usuário através do findById, mas o STATUS no Postman fica como 200 e não exibi nada.
Código abaixo.

controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/bank")
public class ClienteController {
    
    @Autowired
    ClienteService clienteService;
    
    //Listar todos os cliente
    @GetMapping("/cliente")
    public List<Cliente> findAll() { 
        return clienteService.findAll();
    }
    
    //Procurar por apenas 1 cliente
    // não esta funcionando. http 200 mas não aparece informação.
    @GetMapping("/cliente/{id}")
    public void clienteFindById(@PathVariable("id")Long id, @RequestBody Cliente clientes ){
        clienteService.clienteFindById(clientes, id);
    }
}
```

Service

```
@Service
public class ClienteService {
    
    @Autowired
    ClienteRepository clienteRepository;
    
    public List<Cliente> findAll(){
        return clienteRepository.findAll() ;
    }
    
    
    
    public Optional<Cliente> clienteFindById(Cliente clientes, Long id) {
        return clienteRepository.findById(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Adicione os códigos fonte como texto na pergunta. Saiba mais Bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Você colocou uma imagem do código e/ou mensagem de erro. Apesar de parecer uma boa ideia, não é! Um dos motivos é que se alguém quiser responder a pergunta, não pode copiar o código e alterar algo dentro. Clique no link [edit] e **coloque o código/erro como texto**. Veja mais sobre isso nesses links - [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/3774), [Postar mensagem de erro como imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7816/3774).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

João, o método na controller está retornando void, quando deveria retornar um Optional de Cliente.

[image: Correção]

Esse ajuste deve resolver o teu problema.

Comment: Valeu funcionou!

Answer (score 0):

Além do `Optional` você também pode utilizar uma `ReponseEntinty`. Inclusive, ao utilizar o `Optional` tome cuidado e verifique se ele está retornando algum valor.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer dessa forma:

Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/cliente/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Cliente> clienteFindById(@PathVariable("id") Long id){
    Cliente entity = clienteService.clienteFindById(id);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(entity);
}
```

Service:

```
public Cliente clienteFindById(Long id) {
    return clienteRepository.findById(id).get();
}
```

Na controller foi adicionado um ResponseEntity e seu retorno terá um status code 200 e o cliente em si.

Na service foi adicionado um get após o findById para retornar o próprio usuário.

Answer (score -1):

Sempre que usar uma controller, arquiteturamente falando, deve-se chamar a service, e na service implementar os metodos. nativamente deste formato que usou o correto seria usar o ResponseEntity, desta forma

> ```
> //Listar todos os cliente
> @GetMapping("/cliente")
> public **ResponseEntity<List<Cliente>>** findAll() { 
>     return **ResponseEntity.ok(clienteService.findAll());**
> }
> ```